# Angular guard is not triggering routing

Tags: angular, authentication, rxjs, store, auth-guard

I am getting values from inputs

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
   this.sessionService.get(form.value.login, form.value.password);
 }
```

then comparing them with db values and if they are correct. I am then updating store

```
get(login, password) {
    this.http.get<Auth>(url)
      .pipe(take(1), tap(data => {
        if (data.accounts.elisa.email === login || data.accounts.elisa.login === login && data.accounts.elisa.password === password) {
          this.sessionStore.update({isAuth: true});
        } 
      })).subscribe();
  }
```

and sending the `isAuth` to `CanActivate` guard

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.sessionQuery.getStoreData$;
  }
```

The main problem is that I can login if the values is correct, but only on second click on submit button. The store is updating correctly after first click and setting `isAuth` value to `true`

`getStoreData$` implementation

```
export class SessionQuery extends Query<SessionState> {
  getStoreData$ = this.select(store => store.isAuth);

  constructor(protected store: SessionStore) {
    super(store);
  }
}
```

And store config

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, StoreConfig } from '@datorama/akita';

export interface SessionState {
   isAuth: boolean;
}

export function createInitialState(): SessionState {
  return {
    isAuth: false
  };
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
@StoreConfig({ name: 'session' })
export class SessionStore extends Store<SessionState> {

  constructor() {
    super(createInitialState());
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of  `getStoreData`

Comment: @PetrusNguyễnTháiHọc updated question

Comment: `The main problem is that I can login if the values is correct, but only on second click on submit button. The store is updating correctly after first click and setting isAuth value to true` -> on first submit button click, it tries to set the store to login. but it's asyn and it takes time. you probably is redirecting the user to another route like `home` immediately, and since the guard is not updated yet, you think login doesn't work on first click. to fix it, you should redirect on callback. (Ps: you didn't include your code for redirect, so this is just a guess.)

Answer (score 0):

Trying `super(createInitialState())` like this

```js
function createInitialState(): SessionState { ... }

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
@StoreConfig({ name: 'session' })
export class SessionStore extends Store<SessionState> {
  constructor() {
    super(createInitialState());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, hope I'll help someone with the same problem =)

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.sessionQuery.getStoreData$.pipe(first(value => value === true));
  }
```